# pythonのクラスについて勉強しているのですが、なにが間違っているのかわかりません

Tags: python

現在pythonを独学しているものなのですが、「みんなのpython（第四版）」をつかっていて、下のように打ち込んだのですが参考書通りの反応をしてくれません。どこがまちがっていて、なにをすればいいのかを教えてください。（pythonのverは3.6.5で、Anacondaのjupyter notebookを使って練習しています）

```
In(1)class Prism:
        def _init_(self,width,height,depth):
            self.width=width
            self.height=height
            self.depth=depth
        def content(self):
            return self.width*self.height*self.depth
In(2)p1=Prism(10,20,30)
     p1.content()
```

参考書には６０００と戻り値がでるとかいてあるのですが、

```
---> 1 p1=Prism(10,20,30)
      2 p1.content()

TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

のエラーが出てしまいます。どうか教えてください。

Comment: 既に回答が出ていますが念のため明記すると、`_init_` でなく `__init__` だということです。アンダースコア（`_`）の数が違います。

Answer (score 2):

コンストラクタの定義が間違っています。

```
 class Prism:
     def __init__(self,width,height,dept):
         self.width = width
         self.height=height
         self.depth =dept
     def content(self):
         return self.width,self.height,self.depth

 p1 = Prism(10,20,30)
```

pythonでのコンストラクタは`def __init__`として定義する必要があります。`def init`はコンストラクタとして扱われませんので、基底クラスObjectのコンストラクタで引数3つのパターンを探しにいったけど、対象がないのでエラーってことです。